# How to convert a float between -1.0 and +1.0 to dB(A) of sound pressure?

Tags: c#, audio, floating-point, naudio, decibel

Using

```
WaveFileReader wfr = new WaveFileReader(file); 
float[] d = wfr.ReadNextSampleFrame();
```

I get a float array `d`. When iterating through `d` using `foreach (float s in d)` I get floats between -1.0 and +1.0. How do I convert them to dB(A) of sound pressure?

EDIT: I solved it using `double db = 20 * Math.Log10(Math.Abs(s));`

Comment: What values are you expecting to see - what range, and in what format?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I am expecting values from -144.0 to 0.

Comment: dB(A) of sound pressure?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Yes.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Your statement makes no sense.

Comment: Where do you get the numbers from?  if it is a physical sensor then I suggest you look a the documentation and look for information relating how the values are scaled.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser: I was trying to make your question clearer by asking you those questions. You can be assured, though, that I will never again "waste your time."

Comment: @PeterM An audio file whose path is in `file`.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You did not clarify the question. The term decibel was in the tags and title and message. If you have no idea what it is, it is just an insult to even answer without haven gotten information about it first. On top of that you tried to tell me your incompetence in crappy german.

Answer (score 1):

The dBA scale is a measure of relative air-pressure.

In this context, we are talking about an audio reproduction system that takes samples at its input and has some type of apparatus that results in sound pressure waves.

Assuming the system is a [linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system), there will be a single value of gain for the whole system, and it will depend on electrical and physical design characteristics.

`Output = Gain * input`

In order to compute a sound pressure value for any given input you will need to conduct an experiment to measure the output pressure of the system, for a given value of Input.

Considering that a sample-value becomes an output voltage at the output of a DAC, and that the output power of the system is proportional to the sound pressure:

`(1) V=IR` and `(2) P = IV`, with a little rearrangement we find that `P=V*V/R`

Therefore Power varies with the square of voltage (or the sample value).

A decibel value is a relative measurement:

`Sdb = 10*log10(S/Sref)`

Where `Sref` the reference measurement point.

Since we have a power relationship between input and output, we get

`Sdb = 10*log10(S*S/Sref) == 20*log10(S/Sref)`

Now, dBA also happens to be a frequency weighted scale, so you will need to apply the filter described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting) to the samples for truly accurate values.

Answer (score -1):

There is no answer to this.

Sound pressure level may be 0 for the *total silence* (deep space or total vacuum), but a negative value just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suggest you do some research on dB scales.  negative values are legitimate.

Comment: One might except to find the pressure of air in perfect vacuum to be *0 Pascals* on the other hand.

Comment: @PeterM I suggest you do some research on sound pressure which is what the question is about.