# iOS AVRecorder peakPowerForChannel - How to read dB Sound pressuer level

Tags: ios, audio

When I monitor peakPowerForChannel, I am getting a nice stream of values, but am wondering what kind of dB is this.

Is this dB FS (Full scale)?  Also, is there a way to convert that value to dB SPL (Sound pressure level)?  Or is there a way to read in dB SPL that I am not aware of?

Any guidance helps.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avTouch/Listings/MeterTable_cpp.html

Comment: What you do is initialize the MeterTable.cpp, obviously downloading the header file as well, and then pass values like so using an Objective-C++ file type that is change your viewcontroller or whatever is using this method from a .m file to a .mm file and then call to the meter table like so:  .. read next comment

Comment: float scale;
  if (_audioPlayer.playing )
  {
    [_audioPlayer updateMeters];
    float power = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_audioPlayer numberOfChannels]; i++) {
      power += [_audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:i];
    }
    power /= [_audioPlayer numberOfChannels];
    float level = meterTable.ValueAt(power);
    scale = level * 5;
  }

Comment: this will get you some headway, to go farther than this, the you may want to start screwing around with the delegate methods in this: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate ... but this is where things start to get very very nasty and will take a lot of effort on your end to make work

Comment: Refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814394/how-to-convert-a-float-between-1-0-and-1-0-to-dba-of-sound-pressure/33814902#33814902

Comment: did you figure it out? how to measure spl meter?